# React Router Redirect is not redirecting

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-router-v4

I'm trying to redirect away from this page after submitting a form. For some reason, it doesn't do anything. I don't get an error and the page stays the same. I'm using react router 4. What am I missing here?

```
handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  if (isObjectEmpty(errorsInForm)) {
    Meteor.call(
      'user.multiplechoice.answer',
      conductedExamId,
      (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          alert(err.reason);
        } else {
          <Redirect to="/test" />;
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: instead of using <Redirect /> try using `this.props.history.push('/test') '

Comment: You should be returning <Redirect /> inside render method. Inside methods you could use history from props to push.

Comment: @tarzenchugh man, thank you very much! I'm facing this problema for a week. And you explain what i dont find before. Thank you again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<Redirect />` is a component which should be returned by the `render` function, not in an event handler. If you want to use the `Redirect` component, you have to set a state when your api call succeded and render the component based on that state.

```
state = {
    formSuccess: false
}

handleSubmit(event) {
    /* Call to api was successful */
    this.setState({ formSuccess: true });
}

render() {
    if (this.state.formSuccess) {
        return (<Redirect to="/test" />);
    }

    /* The rest of your render function */
}
```

If you don't want to use the `Redirect` component and simply want to redirect, you have to have access to the history of your `Router` component. You do that by wrapping your component that has the `handleSubmit` function with the `withRouter` HOC to give it access to the history.

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

class MyAwesomeFormComponent {
    handleSubmit() {
        /* Call to api was successful */
        this.props.history.push("/test");
    }
}

export default withRouter(MyAwesomeFormComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

First use Higher Order Component  **withRouter** from react-router-dom
‘’’
Then use this.props.history.push(“route-path”);
‘’’